# jQuery Validate errorClass not working

Tags: jquery, validation

I have this validation code:

```
$("#validate").validate({
        rules: {

            // My other rules
            // My other rules
            // My other rules

            minecraft: {
                required: true,
                remote: "./validate-minecraft.php"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            minecraft: {
                remote: "error."
            }
        },
        errorClass: "help-inline",
        errorElement: "span",
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            jQuery("#btn-submit").addClass("disabled");
            ("validate").submit();
        }
    });
```

Everything works correctly excepts for the minecraft field, with remote.

My PHP script validate-minecraft.php returns true or false correctly, the error message is displayed correctly if it returns false, however **the field color is changed to green instead of red when there is an error**.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to remove the "success" class on highlight.

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('success');    
    $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
},
```

When I tested on your site, I noticed that the control-group div looked like this:

```
<div class="control-group success error">
```

Now the weird thing is that it does this even when error on my first try. Not sure how the success class gets added. But maybe this is has to do with the `remote` validator? I tried this locally with a `digits` validator and it did not add the `success` class on the initial error.

Either way you should remove the `success` class on user input error anyway.